# python wsgi pymorphy2 error iternal

Tags: python, wsgi

trying to return value of pymorphy2 using apache with wsgi module & getting error 500
log says  TypeError: sequence of byte string values expected, value of type Parse found

i dont know what to do! in Python im rookie

my python code is

```
import pymorphy2
import cgi

morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
morphid = morph.parse(u'конь')

def app(environ, start_response):
    words = morphid

    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    return [words]
```

---

but in shell it works...  :(
please help i dont understand what is form or type of var words need to me.

or may be that is all wrong

in shell result is

> > > morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
> > >
> > > words = morph.parse(u'конь')
> > >
> > > print "words"

```
[Parse(word=u'\xf1\xf2\xe0\xeb\xe8', tag=OpencorporaTag('LATN'), normal_form=u'\xf1\xf2\xe0\xeb\xe8', score=1.0, methods_stack=((<LatinAnalyzer>, u'\xf1\xf2\xe0\xeb\xe8'),))]
```

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: try printing `type(morph.parse(u'конь'))` to the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, you need to return sequence of byte string but you are returning word which is of type `Parse`. if you want the response to be exactly the same as the thing you get from the console, try

```
words = str(morphid[0]).encode()
```

It will return the string of the result which is `encoded()` thus can be used as a response.

Comment: @parserbot it would be nice to accept and vote the answer :)

Comment: Thanks for tip, but im new here & cant voting